# On "User History" page, "change filter" is cut off by the bottom of content div

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

On "User History" page in diamond mod tools, moderators can filter the events that are visible to only see events in a particular category.

If a filter with only a few events is active, so that the user history table is short, then the "change filter" dialog (red box in screenshot below) is cut off at the bottom. Then, some of the options are not visible.

Here's a (heavily redacted) screenshot:

[image]